# Expression blend 2012 compatible with Visual Studio 2008

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2012, expression-blend

We are using Visual Studio 2008 and targeting the .NET framework 3.5.  I have both Visual Studio 2008 and 2012 installed.  I am looking at creating a WPF project for the user interface and was hoping to use Expression Blend.  My question is - are projects created in Visual Studio 2008 compatible with the Expression Blend that is bundled with Visual Studio 2012?

If not, then is there an older version of Expression Blend that can be used that is compatible with Visual Studio 2008?  If true, is there a link or download for it?  Are there any other graphic design programs that produce good XAML that will be compatible with VS 2008?

Comment: It looks like you already have your answer, but I'll add that there are no other Visual XAML editors.  And be warned: Blend 2 is quite different from later versions.  I'm taxing my memory, but Blend 3 may also work with VS2008.  Blend 4 was VS2010 and .NET 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Microsoft Expression Blend 2 can be used with Visual Studio 2008.

**EDIT**

@Joel, yes thanks for pointing out that Blend 3 can also be used with Visual Studio 2008 which is quite apparent from this Microsoft [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295109%28v=expression.30%29.aspx).